# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

The Operations Research [first full Moderator election](https://or.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and your first non-pro-tem team are:

[image: TheSimpliFire]

[image: prubin]

[image: EhsanK]

You can find them listed on [the moderators tab](https://or.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) — please thank them for volunteering!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: LarrySnyder610]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5369903721742336).

Answer (score 5):

**Congratulations!**

To @[TheSimpliFire ♦](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/123/thesimplifire) and @[EhsanK ♦](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/36/ehsank) continuing on, great job and keep it up.  To @[prubin ♦](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/67/prubin), thanks for stepping up, your diamond is well-deserved.

A hearty thank you to @[LarrySnyder610](https://or.stackexchange.com/users/38/larrysnyder610) for a job well done.

Comment: Thank you and I appreciate all you do on the site

Comment: Thank you for the kind words.

Comment: Thank you for the support, and also to you for your moderation activities.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to everyone who voted in this election. Big thanks to @LarrySnyder610 for all his work from the inception of this site and also as a moderator. Looking forward to continuing on with the help of the community.

And of course thanks to @Eduard and @your_boy_gorja for stepping up and nominating themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats to @TheSimpliFire, @EhsanK, and @prubin! It's been great being a mod on this site and I'm looking forward to continuing to engage with the site, minus my diamond. :)

Comment: Larry, big thanks for going through the work of launching this site (and then serving as pro tem mod). Being part of the Stack Exchange network should give us stability (and definitely gives us technology) that previous iterations (sci.op-research, OR Exchange) lacked.

Comment: It's been my pleasure, and definitely a team effort!

Comment: Big thanks from myself too, you have provided the foundations without which the site would be nowhere as thriving as it is today.

Comment: Thanks @TheSimpliFire, it's been great serving with you as a mod.